# system wont boot up after powering off due to low power

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard

Recently, I have changed my cooling fan and applied thermal paste to the heatsink of a Dell inspiron 1545. The system worked perfectly for 1 day, then due to low power it powered off.

Now it won't boot up (it is receiving power to the motherboard).

Also I have noticed that motherboard receives power only when battery is plucked in.

What might be the reason?

update:

For starting the system, i had to remove and plug again the same CMOS battery. Also, whether system shuts down due to low power or is manually powered  off, same CMOS battery needs to be removed and plugged again.
while starting the system i need to just plugin the AC supply and it will boot on automatically, without pressing the power on button.

Comment: You have verified any cables you removed are firmly connected?  It sounds like you suffered a hardware failure if it fails to boot when not on battery power.

Comment: I hope you applied thermal paste, not thermal glue.

Comment: yes it was thermal paste. Motherboard receives power only when both battery and AC supply are plugged in. As for loose cables system worked for  1 full day after changing fan.